# Django customization of loading a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Assume I have three related classes such as:

```python
class A:
  ...

class B:
  ...
  a = models.ForeignKey(A, ...)

class C:
  ...
  b = models.ForeignKey(B, ...)
```

I want to customize accessing `b` on `C` object to load `a` immediately. It means whenever I called `c.b` a `select_related` query call `a` too. There are also other scenario which I need to be able to use `prefetch_related`.

I am using `django 3.1.1`

Comment: You can try using a custom manager and setting it to be the base manager by setting `_base_manager`. See [Base managers (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#base-managers). (Base managers are the ones used for accessing related objects)

Comment: Is it possible to define different `base_manager` for a same class when use in different foreign keys?

Comment: A model would only have one base manager, what do you mean by the above? Do you mean you want to perform `select_related` on different models based on the fk used? Anyway your use case is really weird. Why don't you simply use `select_related` on `C` directly when you need to.

Comment: `C` has used in other models and I do not want to define a `Manager` for all of them to load `C` also force all of them to load parameters of `C` too. Also `b` in `C` would not be used all times. I understand what you mean by simply call `select_related` but I think in scenarios like what I said it is not a feasible solution and `base_manager` could be a good option.

Comment: If it is not very clear you would be making a base manager for `B` here. Whenever any model would need to access their related `B` instance they would use it's base manager. So it is not a base manager on the `C` model. Also the base manager and default manager can be different if you are concerned about always loading related models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you want to reuse some select_related() with foreign keys :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors import ForwardManyToOneDescriptor


class FullBForwardManyToOneDescriptor(ForwardManyToOneDescriptor):
    def get_object(self, instance):
        qs = self.get_queryset(instance=instance).select_related("a")
        # Assuming the database enforces foreign keys, this won't fail.
        return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))


class FullBForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    forward_related_accessor_class = FullBForwardManyToOneDescriptor


class C:
  ...
  b = FullBForeignKey(B, ...)

class D:
  ...
  b = FullBForeignKey(B, ...)

class E:
  ...
  b = FullBForeignKey(B, ...)
```

You can create other classes inheriting ForwardManyToOneDescriptor and ForeignKey for each of your use cases, if you have many use cases for B foreign key.

```
class F:
  ...
  b = SomeExtraBForeignKey(B, ...)

class G:
  ...
  b = SomeExtraBForeignKey(B, ...)
```

Comment: as far as I understand he/she wants load b and "a" inner relation together, why just didn't use chain select related like objects.select_related("b__a")?

Comment: @VeliEroglu because it seems he/she does not want to duplicate the select_related("b__a") everywhere. This way you can write business logic code without having interleaved optimization code like select_related() or prefetch_related() everywhere.

Comment: Using `forward_related_accessor_class` is a convenient way to deal with scenarios with different loading behavior for a model in different related classes.